# how to make image scale automatic to screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm making webpage by wordpress but I think I need maintenance page during design.
I am beginner so I make an under construction page by photoshop.
I posted this image but it is so big.
The image size is 1920*1028 and Now I use "simplest" theme.
I want no x-scroll, one page image at one time.
Is there any ways to do? Pleas let me know.

```
<html lang="ko-KR"><head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://graphicnet.kr/wp-content/themes/simplest-child/style.css">
        <link rel="pingback" href="http://graphicnet.kr/xmlrpc.php">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title=" » 피드" href="http://graphicnet.kr/?feed=rss2">
        <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title=" » 댓글 피드" href="http://graphicnet.kr/?feed=comments-rss2">
        <link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://graphicnet.kr/xmlrpc.php?rsd">
        <link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://graphicnet.kr/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml"> 
        <meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.8.1">
    </head>
    <body class="blog logged-in">
        <div id="container">
            <div id="header">
            </div><!-- header -->
            <div id="content">
                <div class="post-113 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-uncategorized">
                    <h2><a href="http://graphicnet.kr/?p=113"></a></h2>
                    <p><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-112" alt="underconstruction" src="http://graphicnet.kr/wp-content/uploads/underconstruction.jpg" width="1920" height="1080"></p>
                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                </div><!-- post_class() -->
                <div class="left"></div>
                <div class="right"></div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div><!-- content -->
        </div><!-- container -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: does your 'under construction' announcement has to be a post? It would be much more easier to fix this if it was a 'page' or even easier if it could be coded into your theme template.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternatively use a plugin that has a "Maintenance Mode". I'm not going to drop any names but a good place to start would be logging into your site and going to the "Plugin" area on the right. From there search for "Maintenance Mode" and several good plugins will show up! Goodluck :) Here is a link to get you started [Here >>](http://wordpress.org/plugins/)